# Can't save values for a react-native TextInput which is created dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, textinput

I am trying to create dynamic TextInputs, and then saving the values of TextInput into another state by indexing through loops, but I am not getting the desired output.

I think the problem is in the loop because the console.log of the `onChangeText` for the value of `i` is always the number of TextInputs.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput, FlatList, Button, } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    const [value,setValue]=useState(1)
  const[textInput,setTextInput]=useState([])
  const[inputData,setInputData]=useState([{index:0,text:''},{index:1,text:''},{index:2,text:''}])
  
  useEffect(()=>{

  addTextInput()

},[value])

const addTextInput=()=>{
  var Input=[];
  for(var i=0;i<value;i++){       
    Input.push(
    <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
    onChangeText={(text)=>{  
      var newarray = [...inputData]
      var index = newarray.findIndex((dd) =>dd.index==i)
      console.log('index',index,'i',i);  //------>idk why but the value of i is always the no of text 
                                         //        input pls hwlp me with 
                                         //      these loop.i think i have done something wrong in here
      newarray[index] = {index:i,text:text}
      setInputData(newarray)} }
 />)

  }
  setTextInput(Input);
}

  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{height:50,color:'green',backgroundColor:'green',marginBottom:20}}/>
   <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-around'}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:20,alignSelf:'center'}}>No Of Tenents:</Text>
        </View>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-around'}}>
          <Button title='1' onPress={()=>setValue(1)}/>
          <Button title='2' onPress={()=>setValue(2)}/>
          <Button title='3' onPress={()=>setValue(3)} />
          </View>
           
        <FlatList data={textInput}
        renderItem={({item})=>{
          return item
        }}/>
          
    </View>
  );
}
const pickerSelectStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputIOS: {
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingVertical: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderRadius: 4,
    color: 'black',
    paddingRight: 30,
  },
  inputAndroid: {
    fontSize: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 8,
    color: 'black',
    paddingRight: 50,
 
  },
});
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',

  },
  textInput: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'black', 
    borderWidth: 1,
    margin: 20
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `let` instead of `var` solved my isuue.

Answer (score 1):

Use **let** in loop to declared i, because let can be only available inside the scope it's declared.[read this]

If you want remove loop,

```
const addTextInput = () => {
var Input = [...textInput];
if (Input.length < value) {
  const InputIndex = Input.length;
  Input.push(
    <TextInput
      style={styles.textInput}
      onChangeText={text => {
        var newarray = [...inputData];
        const index = newarray.findIndex(dd => dd.index === InputIndex);
        newarray[index] = {index: index, text: text};
        setInputData(newarray);
        console.log(newarray);
      }}
    />,
  );
} else {
  Input.pop();
}
setTextInput(Input);
```

};

Comment: Thanks brother the only problem was that I was using ``var`` instead of ``let``.